Characterization of the measurability of a function with real extended line as codomain
Theorem. Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ a measurable space and consider $f:X\to [-\infty,+\infty]$.
$$f \hspace{5pt} \mathrm{is\hspace{2pt} measurable} \hspace{5pt} \iff  f^{-1}\left((a,+\infty]\right)\in \mathcal{M}, \hspace{3pt} \forall a\in \mathbb{R}$$
Proof.
$\Longrightarrow)$ It obviously follows from the definition of measurable function.
$\Longleftarrow)$ Let $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=[-\infty, +\infty]$. The family $\mathcal{B}=\{(\alpha,+\infty], \hspace{3pt} \alpha\in \mathbb{R}\}\cup \{[-\infty,\beta), \hspace{3pt} \beta\in \mathbb{R}\}$ it's a prebase of the euclidean topology $\tilde{\eta}$ (compactified with two points) on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. So, a countable base for $\tilde{\eta}$ is given by the family of all finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{B}$.
For convenience, let's define:
$$I_1=\{(\alpha,+\infty], \hspace{3pt} \alpha\in \mathbb{R}\}$$
$$I_2=\{[-\infty,\beta), \hspace{3pt} \beta\in \mathbb{R}\}$$
$\Longrightarrow \mathcal{B}=I_1\cup I_2$.
Now, take $G\in \tilde{\eta}$. Then, we can write $G$ as it follows:
$$G=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\bigcap_{j\in J_n\subseteq \{1,2\}} I_{n,j}\right)$$
Therefore, $$f^{-1}(G)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\bigcap_{j\in J_n\subseteq \{1,2\}}f^{-1}(I_{n,j})\right)\in \mathcal{M}$$
By hypothesis, $f^{-1}\left((a,+\infty]\right), \hspace{5pt}\forall a\in \mathbb{R}$.
We just need to prove that $f^{-1}\left([-\infty,b)\right)\in \mathcal{M}, \hspace{5pt}\forall b\in\mathbb{R}$. We have that:
$$f^{-1}\left([-\infty,b)\right)=X\setminus \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} f^{-1}\left(\left(b-\frac{1}{n},+\infty\right]\right)\in \mathcal{M}$$
$\Box$
I have two questions.

What exactly does writing $f^{-1}(G)$ tell me and why that union/intersection is measurable?

Why is it enough for me to demonstrate that the counterimages of the elements of the prebase are measurable to conclude that $f$ is? More generally, if I have on the codomain a sigma algebra generated by a topology, is it enough for me to show that the counterimage of the open sets (of a base) is measurable to conclude that $f$ is measurable?



I think the most natural solution to this problem is the following two steps:

$\{(a,+\infty]:a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ generates the borel $\sigma$ field.
The subset family of $[-\infty,+\infty]$
$$\{E\subset [-\infty,+\infty]:f^{-1}(E)\in \mathcal{M}\}$$
is a $\sigma$ field.

The first thing is almost the definition of borel $\sigma$ field.
The second thing is true because $f^{-1}$ is interchangeable with intersection, union, and complement operations and $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$ field.
With these two things, we can conclude that the preimages of all sets in the borel sigma field under $f$ are in $\mathcal{M}$.

OK thank you. To see if I understand correctly: suppose that $(X,\mathcal{M})$ is measurable space, $\eta$ is the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Then, I can prove that a certain function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is $(\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ measurable by showing that the counterimage of any open interval $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}, a<b$ is measurable?

Yes, since all open intervals can also generate borel $\sigma$ field.

Thank you very much.
